# Redis instances for all applications? What are some conventions?

Tags: redis

I'm spooling up some redis clusters to implement high availability and replication but I have a few questions from a conventions stand-point. If I have 2 applications that need to use redis, is it better to run 2 redis instances completely independent of the other each with their own replication instances? Or just have 1 redis instance for all applications?

Does redis allow me to have key values stored in a manner such that app1 will be able to reach in and get it's own keys, and app2 can reach in and get it's own keys from the same instance?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have very good reasons to do so (i.e. sharing data), I recommend that you refrain from sharing Redis instances between applications. Why? Simply because sharing can cause the performance of one app to be impacted by the activity of the other app.

By provisioning dedicated Redis instances per application, you'll be decoupling your apps in that tier and since Redis is quite lightweight, the overhead of keeping multiple instances is negligible.

Comment: Also, failing one app's redis won't destroy the other app. It is definitely a better choice. Managing dumps and backups would be a nightmare otherwise too.

Answer (score 0):

Since Redis does not have users or access control the answer depends on how each application interacts with Redis. Generally speaking all client connections to Redis will have access to all databases and all keys, so as long as both applications use unique key names it should be fine to share the same instance.

The other main consideration is how much storage each application will need from the Redis server, if both applications store small amounts of data in Redis it should be fine to share the instance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but Redis does have a user system, but I know it didn't always have one.